# Why am I getting this output while using split() in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am running this code, and I used indices in the order of (2, 1) on purpose.

```
a1 = np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6)
print(a1)
a, b, c = np.split(a1, (2, 1))
print("A is\n",a)
print("B is\n",b)
print("C is\n",c)
```

And this is the output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]]
A is
 [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]]
B is
 []
C is
 [[ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]]
```

I understand that I am getting `b = []` because I used indices (2, 1). But why am I getting the c output from 1st index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html#numpy.split):

> If `indices_or_sections` is a 1-D array of sorted integers, the entries
> indicate where along `axis` the array is split.  For example,
> `[2, 3]` would, for `axis=0`, result in

> ```
>  - ary[:2]
>  - ary[2:3]
>  - ary[3:]
> ```

I.e., your example `a, b, c = np.split(a1, (2, 1))` translates to:

```
a = a1[:2]
b = a1[2:1]
c = a1[1:]
```